# Replacing NaN values in one column with regex from another column

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, nan

This is a small example of the data I am working with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EntryStreetName': ['Palm Avenue', NaN, 'Peachtree Street'],
    'ExitStreetName': [NaN, 'Palm Avenue', 'Mitchell Street'],
    'Path': ['Palm Avenue_NW_Mitchell Street', 'Mitchell Street_SE_Palm Avenue', 'Peachtree Street_NE_Mitchell Street']})
```

I am trying to extract the first part of `Path` to replace the NaN values in `EntryStreetName`.

I set up the below function (beginner here):

```
def empty_streets(data):
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if row['EntryStreetName'] == np.nan:
            row['EntryStreetName'] = re.match('[^_]*', row['Path'])
    return data
```

However it returns the following in the cells:

```
 <re.Match object; span=(0, 38), match='0      ...
```

Is there a tidier way to do this that will return a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be simpler to just split the string on underscore?

```
df['Path'].str.split('_', 1).str[0]

0         Palm Avenue
1     Mitchell Street
2    Peachtree Street
Name: Path, dtype: object
```

After this, use `fillna` for the final step of filling NaNs.

```
df['EntryStreetName'] = df['EntryStreetName'].fillna(
    df['Path'].str.split('_', 1).str[0]))
df

    EntryStreetName   ExitStreetName                                 Path
0       Palm Avenue              NaN       Palm Avenue_NW_Mitchell Street
1   Mitchell Street      Palm Avenue       Mitchell Street_SE_Palm Avenue
2  Peachtree Street  Mitchell Street  Peachtree Street_NE_Mitchell Street
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a [`Match` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). It has methods that you can call to get the desired parts of it.

Check out `.group`, it returns a capture group. In regular expressions, the whole match is always group `0`, and individual capture groups defined with `( )` are then group `1`, `2`, etc.

So, you can use `.group(0)`:

```py
row['EntryStreetName'] = re.match('[^_]*', row['Path']).group(0)
```